# How to select multiple options if check option from a different select?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want select multiple option from second select depending on check option from first select.

For example:

adiunkt -> mikroklimat, RTG

agent celny -> zapylenie

First select:

```
<select name="form[stanowisko][]" id="stanowisko">
<option value="adiunkt">adiunkt</option>
<option value="agent celny">agent celny</option>
</select>
```

Second select:

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="form[czynniki_szkodliwe][]" id="czynniki_szkodliwe">
<option value="mikroklimat">mikroklimat</option>
<option value="RTG">RTG</option>
<option value="zapylenie">zapylenie</option>
</select>
```

I tried this but it not working (select all options after first check):

```
function tes(){
if (document.getElementById('stanowisko').value ="agent celny") {
document.getElementById('czynniki_szkodliwe').options[2].selected = true;
document.getElementById('czynniki_szkodliwe').options[0].selected = true;
}

if ( document.getElementById('stanowisko').value="adiunkt") {
document.getElementById('czynniki_szkodliwe').options[1].selected = true;
}
}
```

Comment: Did you try anything ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a `data` attribute to mark the options linked to the first `select` like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#stanowisko").on("change", function(event){
    var $options = $("#czynniki_szkodliwe option");
  
    //Unselect all
    $options.prop("selected", false);
    var val = $("#stanowisko").val();
    $options.each(function(idx, item) {
      if($(item).data("stanowisko").indexOf(val) >= 0) {
        $(item).prop("selected", true);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="form[stanowisko][]" id="stanowisko">
  <option value="">Choose</option>
  <option value="adiunkt">adiunkt</option>
  <option value="agent celny">agent celny</option>
  <option vlaue="lekarz">lekarz</option>
</select>

<select multiple="multiple" name="form[czynniki_szkodliwe][]" id="czynniki_szkodliwe">
  <option data-stanowisko='["adiunkt"]' value="mikroklimat">mikroklimat</option>
  <option data-stanowisko='["adiunkt","lekarz"]' value="RTG">RTG</option>
  <option data-stanowisko='["agent celny"]' value="zapylenie">zapylenie</option>
</select>
```

**Edit:** If several `options`, from the first `select`, refers to the same `options` in the second `select`, you can "store" an array in the `data` attribute in JSON format.

I updated the JS code to handle JSON array in the `data` attributes instead of a simple `string`.

Comment: This solution does not clean the result after each selection (As in my attempts)

Comment: @AndrzejKowalski Updated answer.

Comment: Great! Is it possible to add an attribute directly in jquery? The form is generated automatically and I can't add it manually :x

Comment: Ok, I did it:  `$("#czynniki_szkodliwe option").each(function(){
  if ($(this).text() == "mikroklimat")
    $(this).attr("data-stanowisko","adiunkt");
 if ($(this).text() == "zapylenie")
    $(this).attr("data-stanowisko","agent celny");
});`

Comment: Of course, with the `data` function (instead of the `attr` function).

Comment: I came across another problem that I can not get around.
For example, I have:

adiunkt -> mikroklimat, **RTG**

agent celny -> zapylenie

lekarz -> **RTG**

How do I change the code to add an attribute so that it changes with each condition?

Comment: Amazing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Pure js solution.

```js
let elem1 = document.getElementById('stanowisko'),
    elem2 = document.getElementById('czynniki_szkodliwe');

elem1.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  Array.from(elem2.children).forEach(v => {
    return v.disabled = v.getAttribute('data-attr') !== e.target.value;
  })
});
```

```html
<select name="form[stanowisko][]" id="stanowisko">
  <option value="">-</option>
  <option value="adiunkt">adiunkt</option>
  <option value="agent celny">agent celny</option>
</select>

<select multiple="multiple" name="form[czynniki_szkodliwe][]" id="czynniki_szkodliwe">
  <option value="mikroklimat" disabled data-attr='adiunkt'>mikroklimat</option>
  <option value="RTG" disabled data-attr='adiunkt'>RTG</option>
  <option value="zapylenie" disabled data-attr='agent celny'>zapylenie</option>
</select>
```